# mongod.service failed, (code=exited, status=14)

Tags: mongodb, ssh, terminal, plesk

we use SSH terminal on Plesk panel, Linode server.
Mongo DB is working.

But when I check the status it shows error.

`sudo systemctl status mongod.service`

[image: SSH Terminal]

Im new to mongodb. Any help ?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Check the logfile, usually at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`. Often the `dbPath` folder does not exist.